# design website from psd when our screen resolution is less than psd

Tags: adobe-photoshop, html

I have got psd of 1800px width from my client that needs to be converted to HTML but my screens are of highest resolution 1366px only. what is best way to design this type of psds? Is there any tools available to change psd in 1366px or some
way to increase screen size. so I can check for pixel perfect output.

Comment: You've discovered why designing sites in Photoshop is a ridiculous method. :)

Answer (score 2):

You will simply have to zoom and pan, unless you want to invest in a better monitor.

**Not** directed at you: I find it somewhat hilarious that *anyone* would ever design a site at 1800px wide. To me that's a clear sign of someone that has little clue about real world usage.

Comment: Zoom and pan makes things difficult as it also doesn't give exact matching resolution. I have asked to provide lesser size psd but client is not ready for that. :(

Comment: Well there's no miraculous way to make a small monitor larger.

Answer (score 1):

I would output at full size and use width:100% and let the browser do the pixel perfect rendering. You can only control so much. If it's that rigid and cannot be scaled, center top left or something and work the design to it.